# Image URL's returned from aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, image

I am trying to display an image that has been uploaded to aws in a react app. What is being returned in the response I am using to try and render my images on the page is something like this:

```
{
description: "Rx Renewal - Bottle"
imageLocation: "attachments/8b2050a1/061e/...
previewImageLocation: "attachment-preview-/...
}
```

and I've tried using the `previewImageLocation` and `imageLocation` as my src in my img element. But all I get is the alt text appearing. The images wont render. Im wondering is there some secret to aws image url's that I'm unaware of? Is it these url's are not what I actually need to render the image? Any insight would be super helpful.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using S3 to host images, but you should add a little more clarity to your question detailing the specific technologies you are using - this will help get an accurate answer from the community.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying this in react app, you should reference to React Amplify Library guide.
Using Amplify Library is the easiest way to interact with AWS services:

```
// get the signed URL string
const signedURL = await Storage.get(key) // get key from Storage.list

// inside your template or JSX code. Note <a download> doesn't work here because it is not same origin
<a href={signedURL} target="_blank">{fileName}</a>
```

The workflow for image presentation is following by (Assuming you can get object key of image stored in S3 bucket from Database or something similar):

- Getting object key of image stored in S3 bucket
- Getting signed URL from this object key by Amplify Library or AWS SDK
- Using this URL to display image or download it

You can do this by using Amplify Lib like above
Cheers